# Autolayout with fixed size view and auto-resizing table view

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, autolayout

I have a view where I'd like to have a "header" type block (a bunch of labels inside a `UIView`) and then a table view below.  The header is to be a fixed size and the table view should expand to the bottom of the view based on what device the application is being run on.

The whole thing is inside a tab bar controller, and I have tried (I think) just about every possible constraint in Interface Builder to try to get the header to be fixed at the top, and the table view to fit the rest of the view, on either a 3.5" or 4" device.

What is happening is that either the header fixes properly and the table view drops below the tab bar, or the header slides under the top nav bar, and the table drops below the tab bar, as well as getting a ton of constraint errors.

Comment: First of all, do you want your header to scroll as your tableView scrolls or you want it to be fixed at the top and let the tableView scroll alone below this header ?

Comment: I would like the header to be fixed at the top and the TableView to scroll alone below the header.

Comment: You can use Stack Overflow's image uploader for your screenshot, you just can't inline the image. If you post the link, I or another member can edit it in for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Step 1

Add a UIView at the top of your viewController's view. Set its `top`, `trailing` and `leading constraints` to `0` and its `height` to what ever you want.
Doing so will fix it on top with a constant height.

[image: Step 1]

## Step 2

Add a UITableView to your viewController's view below the blue UIView. Set its `leading`, `bottom` and `trailing constraints` to `0`. If you can, also set its `top contraint` to `0`. In my case I did not exactly stick it to my blue view. It is 8 point below but never mind I will fix this in step 3.

[image: Step 2]

## Step 3

Now I select the `top constraint` and set its constant `0` instead of `8`. You should see the tableView changing its height to fit the space below the blue view.

[image: Step 3]

## Step 4

If your blue view goes under the navbar, you have to change its `top constraints` to `84`. This is because the status bar `height` is `20` and the navigation bar `height` is `64`.

[image: Step 4]

Comment: Thank you!  Looking back at my project the piece I missed was setting the height constraint on the top view...  your description was excellent...thanks again!

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for and opened my eyes to how constraint work thanks bud!

Answer (score 0):

Ok bit of a tricky one without a screen shot, but here are somethings that might help.

1.Your two views have the same superview in interface builder.
2.Your header view should have a leading constraint to superview set to 0, a trailing constraint to superview set to 0, a top constraint to superview set to 0 and a fixed height constraint set to what ever you like > 0.
3.Your TableView should have a leading constraint to the superview set to 0, a trailing constraint to the superview set to 0, a vertical constraint between the header and its self set to zero and a bottom constraint to the superview set to zero.

If these are set and you can't get the desired effect. Make sure the views are the sizes you think i.e. set the TableView background to pink to make sure it is not just a cell in the wrong place instead of the tableview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you... my issue turned out to be that my top "header" view did not have a height constraint set on it which was causing the 2 views to end up where I didn't want them on the superview at run time.